# Handle several collections of children items on data import

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I managed to import the data with Parent-Child relations (below you can see that I have several pipelines for different types of items - red for parent; green for subfolder; blue for children). However, I need to have children of different templates under the parent (Folder Assets on the image below).

[image]

I thought that I can try to extend the second Pipeline like below:

1.Select Languages

2.Resolve Product Model

3.Apply Mapping

4.Update Sitecore Item

5.Get Product Folders

6.Iterate Product Folders

**7.Get Asset Folders (use another property of a parent object)**

**8.Iterate Asset Folders (pointer to a new pipeline which will handle Assets)**

However, this solution doesn't work (it seems that If we changed the context to a child pipeline in step 6 then we can't go back to step 7). Do you have any suggestions how to setup the pipeline batch to reach the goal?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Is you import an one-time operation or are you planning on running this regularly / periodically?

Comment: It will be loaded regularly.

Comment: Ok, is there a reason you’ve down this all via pipelines? It all seems a bit complex even for a regular import. Have you looked at other options?

Comment: It was suggested to use DEF. Which options do you mean? Sitecore Commerce Connect?

Comment: Ahr ok so the items above are items imported into a Sitecore Commerce Catalog. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Override `SetObjectOnPipelineContext` method of`CopyObjectFromContextToNewLocationStepProcessor` with

```
 public class MyCopyObjectToNewLocation : DataExchange.Processors.PipelineSteps.CopyObjectFromContextToNewLocationStepProcessor
{

    public override bool SetObjectOnPipelineContext(object obj, Guid location, PipelineContext pipelineContext, ILogger logger)
    {

        if (location == ItemIDs.PipelineContextIterableData)
        {
            var plugin = this.GetPipelineContextPlugin<IterableDataSettings>(pipelineContext, false);
            if (plugin != null)
            {
                pipelineContext.RemovePlugin(typeof(IterableDataSettings));
            }

            plugin = new IterableDataSettings(obj as IEnumerable);
            this.AddPluginToPipelineContext(plugin, pipelineContext, false);
            return true;
        }

        return base.SetObjectOnPipelineContext(obj, location, pipelineContext, logger);
    }
}
```

Find `__Standard Values` of `Copy Object from Context to New Location Pipeline Step` template and update `Process Type` with your fix.

Verify that pipeline steps created on this template were updated.

**Solution 2**

Solution 1 is hint where problem is. There is an issue with itarable data location. Certainly for this location it checks if it's already set then skip it. It means the next using of this location in the current pipeline will never assign new object to `Pipeline Context Iterable Data` location.

As workaround you can use `Pipeline Context Temp Storage` instead of `Pipeline Context Iterable Data`

Comment: Thanks! I have decided to use the second approach. it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar requirement, i wanted to create child category items under the product. I used above 'Vlad' inputs and added pipeline step 'Get Catalog item'.

As mentioned in the below image for resolve category child item, I set 'Parent for item location' as 'Pipeline Context Parent Target', it helps me to create child categories under product.

[image]